# How to print strings from a list in sequence in Python?

Tags: list, python-3.x, printing, sequence

Suppose a list: `s = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"]`

I understand how to print every item in the list:

```
for i in s:
    print (i)
```

which gives:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
```

But suppose I want to split the printing in terms of `n`. So if `n = 3`:

```
A
B
C

D
E
F

G
H
I

J
```

These are my attempts:

```
k = 0
for i in s:
    while k < n:
        k += 1
        print (i)
```

and

```
k = 0
while k < n:
    for i in s:
        print (i)
    k += 1
```

I understand that my attempts are way off, but I can't seem to get it.
I know you can create sub-lists in terms of `n` and solve it that way, but is there a way you can do this otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
k = 0
for i in s:
    if k == n-1:
       print i + '\n'
       k = 0
    else:
        print i
        k += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"]
>>> n=3
>>> print('\n\n'.join(['\n'.join(s[i:i+n]) for i in range(0,len(s),n)]))
A
B
C

D
E
F

G
H
I

J
```